# Dilemma with mouse clicking in a rectangle

Tags: python, click, pygame, mouse, blit

So my idea is that i have a windowSurface.blit rectangle and when I press it with left mouse click it shall do these commands `MOVE_SPEED = 9 end_it_levels = True` but I can't wrap my head around how to do that. The mouse functions are found here http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#comment_pygame_mouse_get_pos

```
buttonEasy = pygame.Rect(10, 150, 200, 90)
buttonNormal = pygame.Rect(220, 150, 200, 90)
buttonHard = pygame.Rect(430, 150, 200, 90)

end_it_levels = False
while (end_it_levels == False):
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
    textlevelFont = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 26)
    level = textlevelFont.render("LEVEL:", True, (BLACK))
    level_levels = textlevelFont.render("Easy = 1, Medium = 2 and Hard = 3"
                                        , True, (BLACK))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_1:
            MOVE_SPEED = 9
            end_it_levels = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_2:
            MOVE_SPEED = 7
            end_it_levels = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_3:
            MOVE_SPEED = 5
            end_it_levels = True
    windowSurface.blit (level, (290, 115))
    #windowSurface.blit (level_levels, (140, 150))
    windowSurface.blit(buttonEasyImage, buttonEasy)
    windowSurface.blit(buttonNormalImage, buttonNormal)
    windowSurface.blit(buttonHardImage, buttonHard)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Basicly this code here but that you click left mouse button and within the coordinates of the blit [buttonEasy = pygame.Rect(10, 150, 200, 90)]

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_1:
        MOVE_SPEED = 9
        end_it_levels = True
```

new dilemma with kind of the same

```
end_it = False
while (end_it == False):
windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
        mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if buttonStart.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
            end_it_levels = True
windowSurface.blit(buttonStartImage, buttonStart)
pygame.display.flip()
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The code until the specific loop:

```
import pygame, sys, random, math
from pygame.locals import *
from threading import Timer


pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

WINDOW_WIDTH = 640
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode ((WINDOW_WIDTH,
WINDOW_HEIGHT), 0)
pygame.display.set_caption('Catch the rabbits!')

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

textFont = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 60)
text = textFont.render("YOU WIN!", True, (193, 0, 0))

rabbitCounter = 0
NEW_RABBIT = 40
RABBIT_SIZE = 64
buttonStartImage = pygame.image.load('buttonStart.png')
background_image = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg').convert()
playerImage = pygame.image.load('Fox.png')
playerImageTwo = pygame.image.load('Fox2.png')
rabbitImage = pygame.image.load('topic_rabbit.png')
rabbitImageTwo = pygame.image.load('topic_rabbit2.png')
buttonEasyImage = pygame.image.load('buttonEasy.png')
buttonNormalImage = pygame.image.load('buttonNormal.png')
buttonHardImage = pygame.image.load('buttonHard.png')
player = pygame.Rect(420, 100, 40, 40)
buttonStart = pygame.Rect(220, 150, 200, 90)
buttonEasy = pygame.Rect(10, 150, 200, 90)
buttonNormal = pygame.Rect(220, 150, 200, 90)
buttonHard = pygame.Rect(430, 150, 200, 90)
rabbits = []
for i in range (20):
    rabbits.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
    - RABBIT_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - RABBIT_SIZE),
    RABBIT_SIZE, RABBIT_SIZE))

moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVE_SPEED = 0

end_it = False
while (end_it == False):
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
            mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if buttonStart.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
                end_it_levels = True
    windowSurface.blit(buttonStartImage, buttonStart)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Do you know if the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event is being caught but, coordinates are not matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to add-in extra events to check for.  There is a `Rect` method just for this kind of thing called [collidepoint](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint)

```
buttonEasy = pygame.Rect(10, 150, 200, 90)
buttonNormal = pygame.Rect(220, 150, 200, 90)
buttonHard = pygame.Rect(430, 150, 200, 90)

end_it_levels = False
while (end_it_levels == False):
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
    textlevelFont = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 26)
    level = textlevelFont.render("LEVEL:", True, (BLACK))
    level_levels = textlevelFont.render("Easy = 1, Medium = 2 and Hard = 3"
                                        , True, (BLACK))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_1:
            MOVE_SPEED = 9
            end_it_levels = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_2:
            MOVE_SPEED = 7
            end_it_levels = True
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_3:
            MOVE_SPEED = 5
            end_it_levels = True
        # Is the left mousebutton being clicked?
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
            mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if Your_Rect.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
                # do stuff...
    windowSurface.blit (level, (290, 115))
    #windowSurface.blit (level_levels, (140, 150))
    windowSurface.blit(buttonEasyImage, buttonEasy)
    windowSurface.blit(buttonNormalImage, buttonNormal)
    windowSurface.blit(buttonHardImage, buttonHard)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you were wanting to do but, I hope this helps.

Comment: Don't know why but clicking on this button doesn't work. [up there]

Comment: Did that. I don't know if i need to post the rest of the code.

Comment: Well anyone else who has ideas/tips?

Comment: @user3232394 what happened to "It **worked** perfectly for what I was seeking"?

Comment: When I tried it on the other part it doesn't change the value of end_it when i clicked on the blit.
`end_it = False
while (end_it == False):
windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
        mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if buttonStart.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
            end_it_levels = True
windowSurface.blit(buttonStartImage, buttonStart)
pygame.display.flip()`

Comment: @user3232394 do you know if the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events are being caught?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I found a typo, sorry. `end_it_levels = True` should have been `end_it = True`